# Style not getting applied in excel with POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI to highlight certain rows of my excel sheet but this does not seem to be working.

I googled a lot but the issue seems to be still there.

Below are the some of the ways I checked and it did not work.

```
HSSFFont font = (HSSFFont) sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();
 font.setBold(true);
 style.setFont(font);
 style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
 style.setFillForegroundColor(new   HSSFColor.BLUE().getIndex());
 cell.setCellStyle(style);
//nextRow.setRowStyle(style);
```

or

```
HSSFCellStyle curStyle = (HSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
curStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
curStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
cell.setCellStyle(curStyle);
```

or

```
HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook) sheet.getWorkbook()).getCustomPalette();
HSSFCellStyle style= (HSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();
HSSFColor myColor = palette.findSimilarColor(255, 0, 0);
short palIndex = myColor.getIndex();
style.setFillForegroundColor(palIndex);
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

Comment: are you sure you are wiring the file? No exceptions?

Comment: Do you use only one style object? Or do you have many. style1, style2,...

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing out. Indeed I was not writing back to excel.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution works perfectly.

```
InputStream inp;
HSSFWorkbook wb = null;
HSSFSheet sheet = null;
HSSFRow hssf_DataRow;
HSSFCell cell = null;

inp = new FileInputStream(FileName);
wb = new HSSFWorkbook(inp);
sheet = wb.getSheetAt(1);

hssf_DataRow = sheet.createRow((short) 1);

cell = hssf_DataRow.createCell(1);

HSSFFont font = (HSSFFont) sheet.getWorkbook().createFont();
HSSFCellStyle style = (HSSFCellStyle) cell.getCellStyle();

font.setBold(true);
style.setFont(font);
style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
style.setFillForegroundColor(new   HSSFColor.BLUE().getIndex());
cell.setCellStyle(style);
```